# Non retina iPad app working fine on retina display iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, retina-display

I have a iPad app which is NOT modified for the new iPad with retina display. But, to my surprise(pleasant) the app is working great without any issues in the retina display iPad. The graphics are just the same. I dont even see any pixelation issues. Can some one explain me the reason behind this? Did apple do something from their end in order to get the non retina apps to work the same way in retina display iPad?

Comment: Like i mentioned in my question, there is no pixelation or scaling issue as well. The images are looking absolutely the same?

Comment: If Apple wants, MapView and WebView can use retina display, but I didn't have a chance to test it. For font rendering, if The New iPad use full resolution for anti-aliasing, you can see better characters as well. How iOS 5.1 really does? Sorry I don't know.

Comment: i dont exactly know what upscaling menas, but if there is some thing like this, then why cant an app designed for iPhone upscale itself and run just the same in iPad???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text and framework images are in high resolution, without the explicit need of the application to do anything.

What does look different are the images you provide with your app, so if your app has a custom UI that is not retina ready, it will look bad.

Comment: I have designed my app by hot coding some of the frames with respect to 1024 x 768 resolution. But even these things look absolutely fine. This made me confused.. Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: When you set the values to the views with CGPoints and CGRects, you are not doing it in pixels, you are doing it in points. For the iPad 1 and 2, 1 pixel is equal to 1 point, but for the new iPad, 1 point is 2 pixels wide and 2 pixels tall, so a view with a width of 10, and a height of 10 (in points), will be 20 pixels wide and 20 pixels tall. That's why your hardcoded values are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The same applies to the retina iPhone. Text is displayed in a double density font, and any embedded images are also displayed x2. In most cases the only change that you make for retina displays is to add double density images, but that is optional.

Edit: This also works with iPhone apps running on the iPad, with one massive gotcha. If an iPhone only app runs on the iPad, it is displayed double density, in portrait mode. But the only way that a developer can actually get his app onto an iPad is to mark it as universal, which means that it loses this support.

Comment: Ooh... this came as a surprise to me. I was under the impression that i need to redesign my apps entirely inorder to make it work on retina display...

Comment: But, philip i have a stupid doubt here. Why cant the same technique be applied for iPhone apps so that they can run on iPad without any pixelation. Please Correct me if my thinking or understanding is wrong

Comment: We can only guess, but probably to encourage developers to make an iPad version of their app.